# Page with JQuery created divs is not displayed

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

The following works fine when i open it manually in chrome. However, a simple spring starter app denies to deliver the file.

The IndexController class works fine without the jquery script

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping({"/index","/"})
    public String index(Model model,HttpSession session) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The html file is correctly delivered if I want to create just one div!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var i;
            for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
                {
                    var elem = '<div>' + '<p>blafoo</p>' + '</div>';
                    $('#container').append(elem);
                }
           });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Foo bar!</h1>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors being returned?

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Comment: To be more specific:
**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException**: _The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup_. **In the browser:**  _`Exception parsing document: template="index", line 9 - column 26`_ which points to the first semicolon of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have a few experience with Thymeleaf. But based on a search here, some users did have issues with Javascript with Thymeleaf.

You can try enclosing the script inside `CDATA`

```
//<![CDATA[
    your script
//]]>
```

or just place the Javascript in an external file.

See:

1. [Thymeleaf and inline scripts SAXParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985898/thymeleaf-javascript-function)
2. [Thymeleaf encoding issues with javascript (using spring mvc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306870/thymeleaf-encoding-issues-with-javascript-using-spring-mvc)